# My scanner (for user input) only reads the first word, How to make it read all input?

Tags: java, input

Well hey guys I was wondering how I could make it so that the scanner accepts more than the first word?

My code (snippet)

```
if (command.equals("diary"))
{
    String stuff;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        stuff = scanner.nextLine();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\text.txt")); //you don't need to create a File object, FileWriter takes a string for the filepath as well
        try {
            writer.write("Diary info: " + stuff);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: How much do you want it to accept? A whole line?

Comment: There are many options, but you need to show us example input and expected output. Without it we can only guess what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `next` will read entire data till next delimiter and since by default delimiter is set of one or more whitespaces you see only first word before such whitespace (or eventually end of data).
To read entire line you can use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.
To read entire data (with many lines) you either can iterate over all lines with

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

or you can just set delimiter to match only end of data. You can do it with

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
```

and just use `scanner.next()` like you are doing now. `"\\Z"` is regex which represents end of entire data. You can also use `"\\A"` to set delimiter as start of data, because delimiters are searched after first character after current position of scanners cursor, so it will never be found making scanner iterating until end of data.

---

Update to answer your comment:

Try moving writer outside of loop like in this code example:

```
if (command.equals("diary"))
{
    String stuff;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\text.txt")); //you don't need to create a File object, FileWriter takes a string for the filepath as well
    Scanner scanner =null;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        stuff = scanner.nextLine();

        try {
            writer.write("Diary info: " + stuff);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    writer.close();

}
```

Comment: Ok I added the loop, but how can I close the writer? If I put it out of the loop, it won't work, and if I put it in the loop. It just gens a new line of course haha

Comment: Just create `BufferedWriter writer` before loop, and close it after loop.